# setText printing out resource id only but not the actual text

Tags: java, android, settext

I have the following codes. I am trying to get the TextView to display "Question 1: What is your name?" (the question text string stored in the String file), but now it is displaying "Question 1: 2131362201". How do I fix this?
Thanks!

### AnswerList.java

```
public class AnswerList {
   private int mQuestion;
       private int mAnswer;

   public AnswerList(int question, int answer){
      mQuestion = question;
      mAnswer = answer;
   }
}

public int getQuestion() {
    return mQuestion;
}
```

### Main.java

```
private AnswerList[] mQuestionBank = new AnswerList[] {
   new AnswerList(R.string.question1, R.string.answer1)
}

.....

int question = mQuestionBank[0].getQuestion();
mQuestionTextView.setText("Question 1:" + question);
```

Comment: What is `mQuestionBank`?

Comment: You probably need to call `getString()` to get the actual string resource.

Comment: "What is your name" is a String. `question` is an int

Comment: __"Question 1:" + question__ results a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getQuestion()` returns an `int`, so you should expect the `id` to be shown. In order to show the string resource associated with that `id`, you need to call `getString()` with a `Context` (such as an `Activity`):

```
String question = getString(mQuestionBAnk[0].getQuestion());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put string into a integer variable, so you get an integer value(id) instead of string.

change

```
int question = mQuestionBank[0].getQuestion();
```

to

```
String question = mQuestionBank[0].getQuestion();
```